# QuickSort - Pivot Selection , Random Element Vs. Random Index

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I have an array of size n which contains number from 1 to 10 ( floating point numbers included). Which strategy is better to pick up a pivot for Quicksort:

1. Picking a random element between 1 and 10.
2. Picking a random index between 1 and n.

I believe the 2nd strategy to be better because of lower probability of picking an element in less than 10% or greater than 10% of the array. However what is the maths behind the 1st strategy? Will the worst case of sorted array be worse for 1st strategy or the 2nd?

Comment: How do you pick a random 'element' between 1 and 10? If you pick a random number between 1 and 10, then making sure that the number is actually an element of the array requires you to search the array. You cannot afford to do that without increasing the worst-case complexity.

Comment: Wll thanks DrWatson. That sounds perfectly legit. But what could be a more rigorous mathematical explanation for 1st strategy? I can do the maths for the 2nd strategy but some how find it difficult to come up with good pivot probability for 1st strategy